# Retrieving Stripe Charge through metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'm trying to get a Charge using Stripe API.

Everything is good but I don't understand why this request is not working:

```
Stripe::Charge.all(metadata: { project_id: an_id })
```

I got error:

> Stripe::InvalidRequestError: Received unknown parameter: metadata

Here's what a response look like:

```
{"id":"ch_1BQIXjGrTKCCbjGtKVJOKzbg","object":"charge","amount":1000,"amount_refunded":0,"application":null,"application_fee":"fee_1BQIXlEsrND8ZkheXtsfgQWj","balance_transaction":"txn_1BQIXlGrTKCCbjGtpSDEu34m","captured":true,"created":1511196887,"currency":"eur","customer":"cus_BnuMP3mm0iEFL8","description":"Don","destination":"acct_1BEzwEEsrND8Zkhe","dispute":null,"failure_code":null,"failure_message":null,"fraud_details":{},"invoice":null,"livemode":true,"**metadata":**{"donation_amount":"10","donation_fees":"0","donation_id":"21110","donation_referer_id":"417","donation_reward_id":"2120",**"project_id":"501"**,"project_name":"Arcadia - Le Concert Classique des youtubers","user_city":"Segré","user_country":"FR","user_email":"simon-chretien@hotmail.fr","user_first_name":"Simon","user_id":"23038","user_last_name":"Chrétien"},"on_behalf_of":"acct_1BEzwEEsrND8Zkhe","order":null,"outcome":{"network_status":"approved_by_network","reason":null,"risk_level":"normal","seller_message":"Payment complete.","type":"authorized"},"paid":true,"receipt_email":"simon-chretien@hotmail.fr","receipt_number":"1097-0153","refunded":false,"refunds":{"object":"list","data":[],"has_more":false,"total_count":0,"url":"/v1/charges/ch_1BQIXjGrTKCCbjGtKVJOKzbg/refunds"},"review":null,"shipping":null,"source":{"id":"card_1BQIXcGrTKCCbjGtKktLMM42","object":"card","address_city":null,"address_country":null,"address_line1":null,"address_line1_check":null,"address_line2":null,"address_state":null,"address_zip":null,"address_zip_check":null,"brand":"Visa","country":"FR","customer":"cus_BnuMP3mm0iEFL8","cvc_check":"pass","dynamic_last4":null,"exp_month":10,"exp_year":2020,"fingerprint":"aMPkqWKgq4dQUnWy","funding":"credit","last4":"8073","metadata":{},"name":"simon-chretien@hotmail.fr","tokenization_method":null},"source_transfer":null,"statement_descriptor":null,"status":"succeeded","transfer":"tr_1BQIXlGrTKCCbjGtjFk4oC0D","transfer_group":"group_ch_1BQIXjGrTKCCbjGtKVJOKzbg"},
```

As you can see there's a metadata => project_id in response

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try to read the documentation first (https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#retrieve_charge). This will give you insight on how to call these method.

Comment: In response, all I can see is `"metadata":{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the comments has said you can use [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#retrieve_charge) if you are looking to return one charge. You would have to pass the charge id to the method:

```
Stripe::Charge.retrieve('ch_1BQIXjGrTKCCbjGtKVJOKzbg')
```

The documentation that you are looking for would be under [List all charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#list_charges). `all` is actually an alias for `list`. Based on the documentation to accomplish what you are looking at doing, you could return all the Stripe Charges and then search for the `project_id` within `metadata`.

Depending on how many charges you have this seems like it would be overkill returning all of your charges. Instead consider only return the charges based on the [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#list_charges-customer)

> Only return charges for the customer specified by this customer ID.

```
Stripe::Charge.list(customer: "cus_BnuMP3mm0iEFL8")
# or
Stripe::Charge.all(customer: "cus_BnuMP3mm0iEFL8")
```

Comment: I am very not happy with this lack of feature, it kills performances. How would you rely on Stripe when you have transactions from 1 million users.

Comment: Well you only get transactions from one user and search the object(s), unless a single user has thousands of purchases this really isnt a massive operation to complete and stripe is extremely well developed (Have you tried using paypal api? stripe is a gift from god in comparison)